# Почему я не могу править вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, правки

Хочу внести правку в [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871740/setstate-without-async), но не могу. Почему?

Answer (score 5):

Потому что в него уже внесли правку, и эта правка висит в [очереди на проверку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/287326).

Как только по ней будет принято решение, можно будет править вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: С его репутацией он уже должен видеть правки и мочь их изменять?

Comment: @Qwertiy не уверен, но возможно это доступно только после 10к https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Лично я такие правки в очередях отлично вижу, так что тут что-то странное

Comment: @Suvitruf [это доступно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) с 2к репутации

Comment: @Qwertiy Более того, если ничего не поменялось, юзер с 2К+ может проигнорировать чужую правку без голосования и перекрыть своей (чужая правка будет отклонена Духом). Но это официально не афишируется и требует ручного ввода URL.

Comment: @Athari, не пробовал. Есть же кнопки "принять и править" и "отклонить и править" - тогда даже второй голос не нужен. Кстати, ручной ввод url обычно заменяется нажатием "открыть в новой вкладке".